# Create multi-day events with gaps in fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I am developing a planning solution using fullcalendar.
I am struggling to find a fullcalendar approach for following requirements:

Case: i want to plan an event of 40 hours by dragging an item into fullcalendar

Requirements

The calendar must create an multi-day event, planning maximum 8 hours a day (5 days in total).
The calendar must show the event in day-mode (timegrid) and in month-mode (timeline)
In day mode, the event must show start, lunchbreak and stop , no all-day events.
In timeline (month-view) , the event must be displayed as one draggable event. It should not plan 8hours a day on weekends, but it should continue planning on Monday.

As fullcalendar events are defined by start and stop date, with no fullcalendar functionality to create gaps (non-business hours, lunch breaks, weekends), it seems i would have to split the event in a chain  of communicating events and build a lot of planning logic for dropping and dragging.

Are there any fullcalender best-practices that can help for these requirements?
Any advice on the approach would be very welcome.

Comment: You could use recurring events - https://fullcalendar.io/docs/recurring-events

Comment: If you have any code at all it might be useful to share some.